# randomly add a class inside a php loop

Tags: php, css, loops, random

I'm using a php loop on my website.
I'm trying to randomly add a class "current" to a div inside this loop.
I know how to do it using jQuery but I'd liek to use php to achieve this.
here is my loop :

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<div id="random_backgrounds">
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<div id="background_directors" class="" background_ID="<?php the_ID();?>" style="background: url(<?php the_post_thumbnail_url( 'large' ); ?>) no-repeat center center fixed" ></div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I'd like to add the "current" class randomly to the "background_directors" div.

can anybody help me with this ?

Comment: First of all: IDs must be unique within a document.

Comment: What do you mean "randomly add a class"?

Answer (score 3):

You can try something like this :

```
<?php 
    if (have_posts()) : 
        $numberPost = count(have_posts());
        $isAlreadyActive = false;
        $i = 1;
        echo '<div id="random_backgrounds">';
        while (have_posts()) : 
            the_post();
            $class = "";
            if(!$isAlreadyActive && rand(0, 1) == 1 || !$isAlreadyActive && $i == $numberPost): 
                $class = "current"; 
                $isAlreadyActive = true;
            endif;
            echo '<div id="background_directors" class="' . $class . '" background_ID="' . the_ID() . '" style="background: url(' . the_post_thumbnail_url( "large" ) . ') no-repeat center center fixed" ></div>';
            $i++;
        endwhile;
        echo '</div>';
    endif; 
?>
```

Comment: You could swap the if conditions to check if `$isAlreadyActive` is false first so it doesn't have to generate a random number every time! :)

Comment: thanks @CyrilBeeckman, sometimes none of my divs get the "current" class added... does the if loops each divs ? i have a doubt

Comment: @mmdwc you cant count your post and make another test if $isAlreadyActive == false AND if you are on the last loop

Comment: @CyrilBeeckman thanks for your reply, can you please help me doin it ? I can't find how

Comment: @mmdwc What is have_posts() ? returning a array ?

Comment: @CyrilBeeckman yes, have_post() returns an array with all my posts.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144322/discussion-between-mmdwc-and-cyril-beeckman).

Comment: @mmdwc code edited for put the current class on last child if nobody have already this class before

Comment: @mmdwc don't forget to click on resolve button if this response works

Answer (score 1):

Somethink like this ?

```
$test = ['class1', 'class2', 'class3'];


<div id="background_directors" class="<?=$test[rand(0,2)]?>" background_ID="<?php the_ID();?>" style="background: url(<?php the_post_thumbnail_url( 'large' ); ?>) no-repeat center center fixed" ></div>
```